# Using Java AWS SDK Vs Android AWS SDK on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Is it possible to use the Java AWS SDK instead of the Android AWS SDK when building an app?
Either way Java is the underlying technology used.

I'm looking to use some services that are not available in the Android version of the SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS Java SDK and AWS Android SDK look very similar. Most APIs are identical. However, AWS Android SDK is optimized for Android platform, in terms of jar size, method count, and memory usage. Even though with great similarity, you can't use AWS Java SDK on Android directly. One noticeable problem is that it has a dependency of Apache HttpClient 4.2+ which is not compatible with Android. BTW, what services do you plan to use in particular?

Comment: I was looking at RDS mostly

Comment: As an effort to make the SDK compact, control plane APIs (like createDBInstance) are usually excluded. Do you mind explaining the use case of manipulating database instances on Android?

Comment: I ended up going with a different approach anyway. It was just out of curiosity