# how to solve duplicate class error in gradle block?

Tags: java, android, gradle

i want to create an objects in my amazon aws server and i add this class for aws uploading objects:

```
package com.appsexpress;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UploadObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientRegion = "*** Client region ***";
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String stringObjKeyName = "*** String object key name ***";
        String fileObjKeyName = "*** File object key name ***";
        String fileName = "*** Path to file to upload ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

            // Upload a text string as a new object.
            s3Client.putObject(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, "Uploaded 
                 String Object");

            // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title 
               specified.
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, 
                fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
            metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 
               couldn't process
            // it, so it returned an error response.
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the 
               client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i add also the next lines in build.gradle(app)as i was have to according amazon aws instructions:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
        layout:2.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
        core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK- 
        Android:parse:1.18.5"
    implementation group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', 
        version: '4.5.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation  'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'
    //Base SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5'
    //AppSync SDK
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.1'
    implementation 
       'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.13.5'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile- 
       client:2.13.5@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth- 
       userpools:2.13.5@aar') { transitive = true }
}
```

and when i run the app its giving me this error about duplicate classes but i need to keep them both
i hope there is a solution for that.

```
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.AWSRequestMetrics$Field found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5)             
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.AWSRequestMetricsFullSupport found in 
modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.AWSServiceMetrics found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.AbstractBase32Codec found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base16 found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base16Codec found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base16Codec$LazyHolder found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base32 found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base32Codec found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base32Codec$LazyHolder found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base64 found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base64Codec found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Base64Codec$LazyHolder found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.BinaryUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.CRC32ChecksumCalculatingInputStream found 
in modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ClassLoaderHelper found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Classes found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Codec found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.CodecUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.CountingInputStream found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.EncodingScheme found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.EncodingSchemeEnum found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.EncodingSchemeEnum$1 found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.EncodingSchemeEnum$2 found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.EncodingSchemeEnum$3 found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.HttpClientWrappingInputStream found in 
modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils found in modules aws-android-sdk- 
core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java- 
sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ImmutableMapParameter found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
 core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ImmutableMapParameter$1 found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ImmutableMapParameter$Builder found in 
modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.NamespaceRemovingInputStream found in 
modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class 
com.amazonaws.util.NamespaceRemovingInputStream$StringPrefixSlicer found in 
 modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ResponseMetadataCache found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
 Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ResponseMetadataCache$InternalCache 
found in modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android- 
sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java- 
sdk-core:1.11.404)
 Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.RuntimeHttpUtils found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ServiceClientHolderInputStream found in 
modules aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk- 
core:2.13.5) and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.StringInputStream found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.StringUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.Throwables found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfo found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfoFullSupport found in modules 
aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfoUnmodifiable found in modules 
 aws-android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) 
and aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk- 
core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils found in modules aws- 
android-sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and 
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XMLWriter found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XmlUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.util.XpathUtils found in modules aws-android- 
sdk-core-2.13.5.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.13.5) and aws- 
java-sdk-core-1.11.404.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)

Go to the documentation to learn how to <a 
href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution 
errors</a>.
```

Comment: What aws instructions are you referring to?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to combine both the java-sdk and the android-sdk.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950878/8413094) suggests that you shouldn't be combining the two.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.13.5'         implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'    these two implementation are not going together but i need the aws s3 for TransferService  and also i need the AmazonS3ClientBuilder its not recognize without it so how to combine these two?