# AWS recognition SDK causes the gradle to not build in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, gradle

I tried manually adding the "aws-java-sdk-1.12.199.jar" to the library and added the line "implementation files('libs\aws-java-sdk-1.12.199.jar')" into the gradle, but it seems to cause the gradle to not build. The console prints "Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted". Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and for the gradle to not build? Any help is much appreciated.

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-rekognition:2.44.0'
//implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.35.0'
//implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:1.35.0'
implementation files('libs\\aws-java-sdk-1.12.199.jar')
implementation files('libs\\aws-java-sdk-1.12.199-sources.jar')

// BEGIN AWS DEPENDENCIES
def aws_version = '2.44.0'
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:$aws_version"
implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:$aws_version") { transitive = true }
// END AWS DEPENDENCIES
//implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.44.0'
//implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.44.0'

//implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.44.0'
//implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.44.0@aar'
//implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.44.0@aar'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Comment: See: [Using Java AWS SDK Vs Android AWS SDK on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28457904/295004)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my .gradle/gradle.properties file resolved it for me:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```